# MySQL is blocking GUI with await

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, async-await

I am using an object that should display when a long SQL statement is running; I trigger this using a boolean and a databinding in the XAML;

```
<window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
    </Window.Resources>
        <Controls:ProgressRing x:Name="PRwaiting" Visibility="{Binding Path=isBusy,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
</window>
```

In the codebehind;

```
public async void DoSomething()
    isBusy = true;
    await LongRunninSQL();
}

private async Task<bool> LongRunninSQL() {
//The isBusy ProgressRing object is visible when I use this delay with a normal SQL statement
//await Task.Delay(3000); 


//Yet, the GUI is blocked when this is executed. (and no progressring is displayed)
string SQL = $"select benchmark(9999999, md5('when will it end?')) AS Benchmark";
Collection = await DBC.SelectAsync(SQL);
```

DBC.SelectAsync:

```
        public async Task<DataTable> SelectAsync(string query)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = query;

                    using (var dataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        dataTable.Load(dataReader);

                        //close Data Reader
                        dataReader.Close();

                        //close Connection
                        this.CloseConnection();

                        //return list to be displayed
                        return dataTable;
                    }
                }
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
```

How can I find out why the SQL statement freezes the GUI, even though await and async are being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a long-standing problem with `MySql.Data`: they included the asynchronous ADO.NET endpoints, but implemented them *synchronously*. Unfortunately, it's something you "just have to know", since AFAIK it isn't documented anywhere except a few Stack Overflow questions.

Since you're working on a GUI application, using `Task.Run` would be an acceptable workaround:

```
public async void DoSomething()
{
  isBusy = true;
  await Task.Run(() => LongRunninSQL());
}
```

Alternatively, you can uninstall `MySql.Data` and replace it with [`MySqlConnector`](https://mysqlconnector.net/), which uses true asynchronous implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; are there downsides to MySQLconnector, or is it "the new way" to use MySQL? I am only using MySQL.Data because I honestly didnt know there were other ways

Comment: @Fimlore: `MySql.Data` is the official one, so I like it because of that. But they don't support true asynchrony, so I don't like it because of that. I'd consider both of them and use the one that seems best; there's no "right answer".

Comment: @Fimlore MySqlConnector isn't "official", if that's important to you. But it fixes a lot of bugs and "gotchas" (like this one) with Oracle's MySql.Data so you may find it worth switching: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs

Comment: Thanks for the advice; the change was a breeze; all I have to edit is how i open the connections, because it doesn't like reusing already opened connections..